# How to free char 3D array?

Tags: c, memory-management

How to free memory in such a string array?

```
char** test[5];
for(int i=0;i< 5;i++)
        test[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 4);
for(int i=0;i< 4;i++){
        test[0][i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        test[1][i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        test[2][i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        test[3][i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        test[4][i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
}
```

Cuz I do something like that and I have memory leaks

```
for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
                {
                    free(test[0][i]);
                    free(test[1][i]);
                    free(test[2][i]);
                    free(test[3][i]);
                    free(test[4][i]);

                }
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                free(test[i]);
```

Comment: `i < 5` should be `i < 4`

Comment: You free everything in the reverse order that you allocated them.

Comment: Just add another loop that frees each of `test[i]`. BTW, it would be easier if you used nested loops, instead of listing `test[0]`, `test[1]`, etc. explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar I've added another loop but still have memory leaks with _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()

Comment: Whats `char** test[5];` even supposed to be? It's not a 3D array, that's for sure. No more than `char**` is a 2D array.